# ExchangeService object for push notification and binding of notification(EWS application)

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

Would it be ok if I used two different ExchangeService objects to subscribe to push notifications and bind the itemId's received in the notifications from the server for the subscription respectively in the EWS application?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!**

Yes!! this is absolutely acceptable in my application which you can see under my github profile github.com/rojobo, I used this approach because I needed separate threads, so I have one thread listening to events/notifications and the other process the bindings/updates/deletes etc.

Comment: @robojo : thanks a lot. Actually i am trying to do the same, but when i am trying to bind the item id received in the notification with EmailMessage object as below i am getting the exception as pasted below, along with some trace information(as what it seems).      EmailMessage emailMessage = EmailMessage.bind(service, itemId, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);  .

Comment: Jun 17, 2016 7:42:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/wcc-exchange-service] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(Ljava/lang/String;)[B] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(Ljava/lang/String;)[B

Comment: Please ignore the above comments as the exception was not related to the email service but rather due to a commons-codec jar issue(older version was used).